# simple envoy filter not being used

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

Hi I'm new to Envoy and Istio. I'm trying to write an envoy filter to rewrite/redirect HTTP(s) requests. Below is my configuration (yes, a toy example) and it's not working.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: lua-filter
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "envoy.router"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
       name: envoy.lua
       typed_config:
         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.lua.v2.Lua"
         inlineCode: |
            function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                request_handle:headers():add("authorization", "it works!")
            end
            function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
                  filter_name = "ENVOY"
                  response_handle:headers():add("my_Filter", filter_name)
            end
```

after I deploy the app (listening on port 443 for https, behind Cloudflare) and envoy filter, I do `curl -v <my_app>`. I don't see either the added request header or the response header. I also tried adding `xff_num_trusted_hops: 2` suggested by some other answers but to not avail. What did I do incorrect?

Answer (score 6):

To apply the filter to a single pod you have to add `workloadSelector` for your app.

```
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      xxx: xxx
```

For example, there is an nginx deployment and your envoy filter with appropriate `workloadSelector` .

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginx1
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx1
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80


apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: lua-filter
  namespace: default
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      run: nginx1
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "envoy.router"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
       name: envoy.lua
       typed_config:
         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.lua.v2.Lua"
         inlineCode: |
            function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                request_handle:headers():add("authorization", "it works!")
            end
            function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
                  filter_name = "ENVOY"
                  response_handle:headers():add("my_Filter", filter_name)
            end
```

---

To apply the filter to all requests going through your istio ingress gateway.

1.Change change context from `SIDECAR_INBOUND` to `GATEWAY` .

2.Set a `workloadSelector`.

```
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
```

3.Set istio-system namespace.

```
  namespace: istio-system
```

4.There is your example after few edits.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: lua-filter
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "envoy.router"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
       name: envoy.lua
       typed_config:
         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.lua.v2.Lua"
         inlineCode: |
            function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                request_handle:headers():add("authorization", "it works!")
            end
            function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
                  filter_name = "ENVOY"
                  response_handle:headers():add("my_Filter", filter_name)
            end
```

5.I checked it with curl

curl -s -I -X HEAD xx.xx.xx.xx/productpage

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 5179
server: istio-envoy
date: Tue, 10 Nov 2020 08:28:30 GMT
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 60
my_filter: ENVOY    <---
```

AND

I checked it with config_dump in istio ingress-gateway pod.

I exec there with

```
kubectl exec -ti istio-ingressgateway-86f88b6f6-2tv64 -n istio-system -- /bin/bash
```

Results from config_dump

```
curl 0:15000/config_dump | grep my_Filter
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  140k    0  140k    0     0   9.7M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  9.7M
               "inline_code": "function envoy_on_request(request_handle)\n    request_handle:headers():add(\"authorization\", \"it works!\")\nend\nfunction envoy_on_response(response_handle)\n      filter_name = \"ENVOY\"\n      response_handle:headers():add(\"my_Filter\", filter_name)\nend\n"
```

---

Additional resources:

- https://discuss.istio.io/t/adding-custom-response-headers-using-istios-1-6-0-envoy-lua-filter/7494/6
- https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/

Comment: thanks! I guess my mistake was that I didn't apply it to `GATEWAY`. I'm using custom-istiogateway so I made some additional changes to `namespace` and `label` field, but your answer fixed my issue here!

Comment: one more question that I haven't found by googling: where do I find the logs? I used https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/lua_filter#log but didn't find anything when I check on `custom-ingressgateway-*` pods

Comment: @user2309838 Happy it works for you. What logs exactly are you looking for? If you mean logs of envoy filter working they i always checked just with curl or with the config dump if it's applied correctly.

Comment: Yep I could see it via curl or increasing loglevel, e.g. request_handle:logCritical